# Couldn't we have defined the material conditional differently?

Tags: logic

I've been mulling this over lately, and I can't seem to understand why exactly the material conditional wasn't defined in a completely different way.

Obviously, the motivation behind our current definition of the material conditional is, amongst others, so that we don't end up with a definition that makes most restricted quantifiers impossible to work with. For example, take two triangles. A triangle is called equilateral if the lengths of its three sides are the same, whereas a triangle is defined to be isosceles if two of its three sides have the same length. We know then, by definition, that any equilateral triangle is also an isosceles triangle.

With this in mind, we can set up the following implication where $P(T)$ and $Q(T)$ are open sentences over the domain S of all triangles:
$$P(T): T \; \textit{is equilateral.} \; \text{and} \; Q(T): T \; \textit{is isosceles.}$$

$$P(T) \implies Q(T)$$

This implication should then be required to hold true for all triangles $T$ that are equilateral, so we could write:

$$\forall \, T, \, P(T) \implies Q(T)$$

but we run into the problem of *"what if T **isn't** equilateral?"* If we choose to define the truth values of the material conditional any other way than we currently have, say by making the implication false whenever $P(T)$ is false, we'd end up with a false implication. But surely, our implication (which we *know* to be true by definition) can't be proven wrong by looking at triangles that the implication doesn't even deal with in the first place. Therefore, we must require this implication to be vacuously true.

However, couldn't all of this have been avoided by simply stating:

$$\forall \, T: \textit{T is equilateral}, \, P(T) \implies Q(T)$$

and assigning a false truth value to the material conditional whenever its antecedent is false? That way, we'd avoid situations like:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \; x>2 \implies x^2>4$$
$$x=-1$$
$$\therefore (-1)^2>4$$

...situations which we *know* to be untrue.

I'm probably not really getting the big picture here, but it seems to me that a simple specification of the properties of a quantified statement fix the issue of quantifier incompatibility. Could somebody enlighten me?

Cheers.

Comment: I don't really get the way you are formalizing: Wouldn't $\forall T:T is equilateral,P(T)\Rightarrow Q(T)$ be saying that "Given any triangle T such that T is equilateral, if T is equilateral then T is isosceles"? Why do you condition on something that is already true in the domain of discourse? Also, from $x>2\Rightarrow x^2>4$ and $x=-1$ because $x=-1$ is not greater than 2, the "whole" implication holds true for that value but not the consequent alone ($\neg(x^2>4)$).

Comment: You may enjoy Angelika Kratzer's paper [Conditionals](https://udrive.oit.umass.edu/kratzer/kratzer-conditionals.pdf) which discusses the material conditional and why it is interesting. It comes to the conclusion that the mathematics uses the material conditional because in a certain sense it is the _weakest possible_ form of the conditional.

Answer (score 4):

Your inference is wrong.

If we start with the reasonable law :

> $∀x \in \mathbb R,x > 2 \to x^2 > 4$

and we instantiate it with $x=-1$, we get :

> $-1 > 2 \to (-1)^2 > 4$.

But we cannot infer the *false* : $(-1)^2 > 4$ because, in order to do it, we have to use *modus ponens*, and to do this we have to assert the *false* : $-1 > 2$, and we have no reason to assert it.

Comment: I see, you're right. But then why is the material conditional defined the way it is? I don't get it!

Comment: @Luke - exactly because we want *modus ponens* to work ... If the conditional $p \to q$ is *true* **and** the antecedent $p$ is *true*, then we want to conclude with the consequent. This fact account for the case when $p$ is *true*. If we set $p \to q$ false when both are false, we have to "break" the equivalence between $p \to q$ and $¬q \to ¬p$. In conclusion, the only "debatable" case is FALSE $\to$ TRUE... but if we change only this one to false what we get is the bi-conditional : ↔.

Comment: Yes, but isn't the bi-conditional defined based on the material conditional? So aren't you essentially referring back to our current definition of the conditional to demonstrate the necessity to define the conditional that way? Besides, why is the equivalence between $p \implies q$ and $\lnot q \implies \lnot p$ so important?

Comment: @Luke - no, forget about *bi-conditional* and call it *equivalence*. It is quite "natural" to say that two sentences are *equivalent* when they have the same truth-value; thus, no material conditional is involved here.

Comment: @Luke : if $p \to q$ is *false* when both are *false*, we have that its *contrapositive* ; $\lnot q \to \lnot p$ will be *true* (because now both antecedent and consequent are *true*). But again, our "intuition" says that if we assert that : "if I'm more than twenty years old, then I was born earlier than 1995", for sure I can assert : "if I was born **not** earlier than 1995, then I'm **not** more than twenty years old".

Answer (score 4):

The one rule that we all agree must work is modus ponens: if we have $p \Rightarrow q$ and $p$ then we must have $q$. This means that $p \Rightarrow q$ must imply $\neg (p \wedge \neg q)$. The question for us is whether this is strong enough.

To help us decide whether that is strong enough, we look at trying to extend our definition of the conditional to first order logic. That is, we turn to statements of the form

$$(\forall x \in U) \: P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x) \quad (1)$$

for predicates $P,Q$ and a domain of discourse $U$. (I ask that you do not bring up set theory issues here.) I think it is reasonable to assert that this should be equivalent to

$$(\forall x \in \{ y \in U : P(y) \}) \: P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x). \quad (2)$$

That is, the members of $U$ which don't satisfy $P$ should not have anything to do with the truth of our statement. This is one point that could possibly be disputed.

The other main philosophical assumption is that in classical logic, every well-formed statement is either true or false. This is the other main point which can be disputed. (This point really is treated differently in some nonclassical logics, such as intuitionistic logic.)

Given these two assumptions, $P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)$ *must* be true whenever $P(x)$ is false, because otherwise there would exist situations where (1) is false and (2) is true. Restricting attention back to propositional logic, we get the classical definition of the material conditional.

Comment: _"P(x)⇒Q(x) must be true whenever P(x) is false, because otherwise there would exist situations where (1) is false and (2) is true."_ - how so? They're not the same statements, so you'd expect them to differ in truth values, right? (2) is essentially a statement that's only ever incorrect when the implication doesn't hold true (P not implying Q), while (1) might have a false P(x) to begin with since the domain of discourse doesn't confine our variables to only the relevant ones. I really think you're on to something here, and it's starting to make sense, so please help me through this.

Comment: @Luke You are asking about the first of my two assumptions, i.e. that (1) and (2) are equivalent. In my answer I assert that this is natural. Maybe an example will help with that. Let's say $U$ is the real numbers, $P(x)$ is defined as "$x$ is an integer", and $Q(x)$ is defined as "$x^2$ is an integer". Do you agree that we should have $(\forall x \in U) \: P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)$? In natural language this should mean "if $x$ is an integer then $x^2$ is an integer".

Comment: @Luke (Cont.) If you accept this, then given the second assumption (that $P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)$ has to have *some* truth value), $P(1/2) \Rightarrow Q(1/2)$ must be true. Similarly $P(\sqrt{2}) \Rightarrow Q(\sqrt{2})$ must be true. Yet in the first case $P$ and $Q$ both fail, while in the second case $P$ fails and $Q$ holds.

Comment: Yes, but why? You assert that they _must_ be true, but I see no reason for asserting that. Why couldn't they be false instead? Moreover, I still don't see why and how (1) and (2) are equivalent. (1) has a domain of discourse containing both relevant and irrelevant variables, while (2) consists of only relevant variables.

Comment: @Luke What do you think about my example in the previous two comments?

Comment: I think it's odd that we'd say "for all real x" when dealing with a statement that's specifically about integers - why not just say "for all integers" and not have to deal with cases like $P(1/2)$ or $P(\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: @Luke Because of the second assumption: the statements "$x$ is an integer" and "$x^2$ is an integer" are well-formed for any real number $x$, so all of them must have some truth value. So under the second assumption you cannot simply dodge the issue, you have to decide whether $P(1/2) \Rightarrow Q(1/2)$ is true or false. If we chose false, then the formalization of "for any real number $x$, if $x$ is an integer then $x^2$ is an integer" would be false. That seems awfully problematic to me.

Comment: @Luke One somewhat abstract place where this is important is when we prove a theorem in the form of an implication, where we do not know whether the hypothesis is true or false. For instance, there are a lot of theorems in modern number theory that say "if the Riemann Hypothesis is true, then ..."

Comment: @Luke Perhaps a natural language analogy will help. Suppose Bob's been having car trouble, and tells Alice "if I make it to the grocery store, I'll buy some apples". She leaves, he tries to drive to the store, but his car breaks down along the way. So he didn't make it to the grocery store and didn't buy any apples. Did Bob lie? (I repeat that in the classical framework, the answer to my question can only be yes or no.)

Comment: If it were only possible for the implication to be either true or false, I'd consider the choice completely arbitrary. He didn't lie, but he didn't tell the truth either. We just don't know. That's why I don't understand our current definition; it just seems so arbitrary and people usually stick to just saying "well, it works". I'm not really used to maths being this random and "pointless"...

Comment: Alright, so that didn't help. Another case to look at: do you accept the equivalence of $p \Rightarrow q$ and $\neg q \Rightarrow \neg p$, i.e. the validity of proof by contraposition? For instance do you think that the proof at this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive#Example is valid? If so, then (yet again stressing this principle that you have to "pick a side") $p \Rightarrow q$ must be true in the case where $p$ and $q$ are both false.

Comment: Look, to get back to the original example: "for any real number x" doesn't make sense to me. Real numbers x don't have anything to do with our statement unless they're integers. It's like involving a completely different thing; "For any elephants x, if x is an integer then x^2 is an integer". Why wouldn't we just say "for any integer x"? Why _must_ we involve things that don't have anything to do with our statements, and why are we then _forced_ to say whether they're true or not?

Comment: @Luke It's more convenient to be able to hold the domain of discourse fixed in order to prove that all members of the domain have some property, or that there exists a member of the domain with some property. This is contrary to how we operate in natural language speech, where we frequently let the domain of discourse change fluidly. Keeping complete track of all this change in the domain of discourse in logic would prove quite cumbersome.

Comment: the contrapositive is defined in terms of our current definition of the implication, so to me it doesn't make a lot of sense to rely on that to explain why the implication is the way it is. The contrapositive of an implication is a "result" of the implication.

Comment: I see. I guess I'll just have to work with this definition then. Either way, thank you so much for all the input - I really, really appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 4):

> ... assigning a false truth value to the material conditional whenever its antecedent is false?

Let's approach $P \Rightarrow Q$ as a truth functional connective. I assume we agree that if $P$ and $Q$ are true, then $P \Rightarrow Q$ is true.
Also, we probably agree that if $P$ is true and $Q$ is false, then $P \Rightarrow Q$ is false.

Using that agreement, and the quoted statement, we would find that the truth table for $P \Rightarrow Q$ is the same as the truth table for "$P$ and $Q$". But nobody thinks that "if $P$ then $Q$" should have the same meaning as "$P$ and $Q$"!  So the quoted statement above can't work if we want to capture "if $P$ then $Q$".

It turns out that, based on basic reasoning about implication, we should have the following three lines of the truth table:

```
P  Q  P => Q
T  T   T
T  F   F
F  F   T
```

That only leaves one missing line: when $P$ is false and $Q$ is true. If we let $P \Rightarrow Q$ be false in that case, we obtain the following table:

```
P  Q  P => Q
T  T   T
T  F   F
F  F   T
F  T   F
```

But that table would say that $P \Rightarrow Q$ is the same as $P \Leftrightarrow Q$. Again, nobody thinks that "if $P$ then $Q$" means the same as "$P$ if and only if $Q$".

The only other option is the actual table for material implication.  So, rather than being arbitrary, the table for material implication is the only choice that matches the three unambiguous lines of the truth table and does not make $P \Rightarrow Q$ the same as $P \Leftrightarrow Q$.

Comment: But isn't that some kind of circular reasoning? The biconditional is defined based on our current definition of the implication, so arguing that the implication can't be any different from how it is now or else it would clash with the biconditional strikes me as circular reasoning. On a different note; how exactly did you arrive at the first truth table?

Comment: The first truth table contains the three lines that are relatively uncontroversial about a truth-functional connective for "if P then Q". If P and Q are both true, or both false, then the implication should hold; if P is true and Q is false the implication should not hold. The fourth row is the one that causes the most consternation.  As for circularity, even before we study formal logic we know that "if N is a multiple of 4 then N is even" is not the same as "N is a multiple of 4 if and only if N is even".

Comment: Yes, we know they're not the same, but before we study formal logic we won't know what their truth values are either. On top of that, I still don't understand why that truth table is the way it is. If P and Q are both false and the implication still holds, I don't really consider that uncontroversial. As for the 4th row; you still haven't explained why it was defined that way?

Answer (score 3):

I think it is illuminating to approach it from the opposite direction.

Suppose we already know we want universal quantifiers (those are easy to motivate, I think), and that we also want to express the idea "everything that satisfies $P$ also satisfies $Q$"). It turns out that exactly this meaning can be expressed as
$$ \forall x\, [ P(x) \triangleright Q(x) ] $$
if $\triangleright$ is a truth-functional connective with the truth table

$$ \begin{array}{cc|c} P & Q & P \triangleright Q \\ \hline
T & T & T \\
T & F & F \\
F & T & T \\
F & F & T \end{array} $$
Since we want to have quantifiers anyway and truth-functional connectives are *easy* to understand and manipulate, this is a wonderful plan! We just need to decide on a name for our connective.

For better or worse, mathematics has decided to use the symbol $\rightarrow$ (or $\Rightarrow$ or $\supset$) to write this connective and to pronounce it with the words "if ... then ...".

But it's really not a matter of "what should the right meaning of the words 'if' and 'then' be?", but instead "what should we call the thing with such-and-such truth table?".

If somehow, we all are convinced that giving "if ... then" this meaning is so confusing and illogical that it needs to be changed, we *would still keep using a connective with the above truth table*. We would just call it something different.

---

It would be *technically* possible to fuse the two constructions together and say that $\forall x$ must *always* appear with *two* formulas: a condition and a conclusion, so $\mathop{\forall x}\limits_{P(x)} [Q_x]$ means what we're currently writing $\forall x[P(x)\to Q(x)]$. Then if we ever needed a quantifier without a condition we could write it as $\mathop{\forall x}\limits_{x=x} Q(x)$.

But this would make things strange whenever we want to quantify over *two* variables -- for example $\forall x \forall y (x<y\Rightarrow P(x,y))$ would now need to be written $\mathop{\forall x}\limits_{x=x} \mathop{\forall y}\limits_{x<y} P(x,y)$, where the dummy condition on $\forall x$ doesn't exactly make things easier to read.

And generally we *want* to split complex constructions into simpler ones whenever we can -- that makes all of the theory simpler. So simply because we *can* split the quantifier-with-condition into a universal quantifier and a truth functional is enough reason to do it.

Comment: Also I think your rejection of OP's requirement of bounded quantifiers is too pessimistic. There are logics and mathematical contexts that require all quantifiers to be bounded, so that "$\forall x"$" is forbidden and only "$\forall x\in S$" is allowed.

Comment: Indeed I think some people would argue that unbounded quantifiers are logically incoherent, and when we omit the bounds it's only by way of a convenient abbreviation when the bound is implied by the context.

Comment: @MJD: Sure, there are contexts that care about bounded quantification -- but in those contexts you generally want tighter control on the shape of the bounds than just "insert some property here", so having a three-place quantifier as the _general_ construct is not going to make it appreciably easier to define bounded quantification. At least not if the general construct is flexible enough to subsume our current use of logical implication.

Comment: I think that is a result of OP's unfamiliarity with how things are actually done. Had they more experience, they might have suggested, instead of $$\underset{\text{$T$ is triangular}}{\forall T.} P(T)\implies Q(T)$$ something like $$\forall T\in{\mathscr T}. P(T)\implies Q(T),$$ where $\mathscr T$ is the set of triangles. We don't do the first, but we do the second, and I imagine OP is unaware of this, and might view it as being sufficiently similar to his or her idea that the question is resolved not as "we don't" but as "we do"—except for the part about redefining the material conditional.

Comment: @MJD I think this is where I lose it

Comment: @MJD This is what bugs me. Why didn't we specify $\mathcal{T}$ to be the set of all _equilateral_ triangles? I mean, we're already using bounded quantifiers, why not do it right the first time around? Thank you for linking to that article by Angelika Kratzer, I'll be taking a look at that now. Still, I think, my chief problem with all of this is simply _why_ the conditional is the way it is. Henning Makholm tried to explain it as having a truth-table that suits our needs and then associating a word to it, but then I wonder; why is the truth-table defined like that!

Comment: @HenningMakholm Alright, but why is that particular truth table the one that expresses the meaning of our truth functional connective? How did we choose that one out of all the others? What makes that one so special? I'm used to maths being proof-based or motivated by arguments, and so far most explanations have tip-toed around the very core of this whole thing: the reason behind our current definition of the implication. And please don't just say "well, that's what worked out" - somebody must have figured out that this particular truth table was superior over all others. Why?

Comment: @luke Were you aware that $\forall x\in S. Q(x)$ is often defined to mean exactly $\forall x. x\in S \implies Q(x)$?

Comment: @MJD Not really, no. But what difference does that make?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seemed pertinent.

Comment: @Luke: There are only 16 possible truth tables for a truth function of 2 operands; it is not difficult to check that each of the 15 others don't give the desired functionality when put under a quantifier (in the sense that you either can have a situation where all $P$s are  indeed $Q$s but $\forall x[P(x)\rhd Q(x)]$ is nonetheless false, or you can have a situation where some $P$s are not $Q$s, yet $\forall x[P(x)\rhd Q(x)]$ evaluates to true).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'll try to figure that out, but I don't think it's going to be particularly fruitful. Quantifiers in general bug me, I think. To me, it's just strange to expect a quantifier that involves a _lot_ of completely irrelevant elements to behave in a certain way. Just seems ill-conceived. It makes no sense to say "for all natural numbers n" when we're really only interested in all _even_ natural numbers n. So I don't even understand why we use quantifiers that way instead of bounding them to our relevant values; much less why I'd have to keep that in mind when defining conditionals.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the statement: If it is raining, then it is cloudy.

> Symbolically: $Raining\implies Cloudy$

What does this mean? First, what it does *not* mean: It does *not* mean that rain somehow causes cloudiness, or that cloudiness somehow causes rain. Neither is the case. It means only that it is not both raining and not cloudy.

> Symbolically: $\neg[Raining \land \neg Cloudy]$

There is no suggestion of causality -- of one thing *causing* another -- or of time-based data about a historical relationships between raining and cloudiness.

Everything about material implication -- the truth table for $\implies$, and the detachment and contra-positives rules -- all make sense when you understand this. Simply stated, the rule is:

> $A\implies B\equiv \neg[A\land \neg B]$

---

**EDIT:**

**The Truth Table**

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
A&B&A\implies B\\
\hline
T&T&T\\
T&F&F\\
F&T&T\\
F&F&T
\end{array}$

**The Intuition**

In the first row, we have $A\implies B$ and $A$ being true. Of course, $B$ must also then be true, as indicated.

In the second row, we $A$ being true and $B$ being false. Then $A\implies B$ must be false, as indicated.

Note that when $A\implies B$ is true and $A$ is false, as you would expect, $B$ is indeterminate, i.e. $B$ could be either true or false, as indicated in the the last two rows.

We also need $A\implies B$ to be true when $A$ is false to prove [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), an essential method of proof in mathematics.

Comment: So the only reason that the conditional is the way it is, is because it's logically equivalent to not(A and not B)? That's it? No profound reason as to why it was defined that way?

Comment: That is correct. I think you will find that this definition works really quite well in writing mathematical proofs. It may seem counter-intuitive at first because the if-then construct in everyday usage usually suggests a causal or temporal relationship. In mathematics, there is no cause and effect and no passage of time. It may help to think of mathematics as a static body of knowledge, aspects of which humans have discovered over the millennia. Cause and effect is the realm of science. But even in science, we don't say, if you smoke then you have cancer. We say smoking *may cause* cancer.

Comment: I think this misses the point, and I think the point here is from [Mauro ALLEGRANZA's comment above](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317408/couldnt-we-have-defined-the-material-conditional-differently#comment2679053_1317540): We define it this way because that's what makes modus ponens work.

Comment: @MJD  In mathematical proofs, we also need $A\implies B$ to be true if $A$ is false. It's not just some undesirable *side-effect* as some would have it; it is essential.

Comment: @MJD  Note, too, that the truth table for $A\implies B$ is not completely determine by the requirement that MP must work. MP determines only 1 out of 4 rows.

Comment: Okay.  I still feel that your answer misses most of the crucial issues, and it doesn't address OP's suggestion either.

Comment: @MJD  We need $A\implies B$ to be true when $A$ is false to establish that certain statements are vacuously true. Another way to look at: If we know only that  $A\implies  B$ is true and $A$ is false, then $B$ is indeterminate -- it could be either true or false.

Comment: See edit above.