# Not understand about meaning of " if P then Q"

Tags: logic

**P | Q | P->Q** 
**T | T | T** (That makes sense) 
**T | F | F** (That makes sense) 
**F | T | T** (Why the anwser is T?) 
**F | F | T** (Why the anwser is T?)

Comment: The idea is that if you begin with a false statement you can prove anything, either true or false.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70736/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-p-is-false-and-q-is-tr

Comment: Another answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208612/logical-conditional-truth-table-rationale

Answer (score 1):

$(P\implies Q)$ merely says that we cannot have $P$ true and $Q$ false. In other words, $(P\implies Q)$ is equivalent  to $\sim (P\land  \sim Q).$

Answer (score 0):

The implication/conditional: "$P\to Q$" means "If $P$, then $Q$" .

It is a guarantee that $Q$ is true whenever $P$ is true.

When $P$ is false, we might say the guarantee is *counterfactual*, but it is not *falsified*.   If the guarantee is not false, what is it?

The guarantee is only considered *falsified* when $P$ is true while $Q$ is false.

So we consider the implication to be true when either $P$ is false or $Q$ is true.   That is $\neg P\vee Q$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I tell you "If it rains in the evening then I will meet you." Then there are four possibilities (Look at the truth table). The only instance my statement is false is when it actually rains and I don't meet you. But my statement will still be true when it doesn't rain in the evening but I come and meet you, and also when it doesn't rain in the evening and I don't come and meet you. All I said was that *if* it rains in the evening *then* I will meet you.