# truth tables and direct proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic

I recently reread about truth tables and I wanted to check whether I understand some things correctly. Essentially, when $p$ and $q$ are formulas of our language, then there is a symbol $p \implies q$ for which one can define the following truth table.

\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 p & q & p \implies q \\
T & T & T \\
F & T & T \\
T & F & F \\
F & F & T
\end{array}

Thus, especially, **if $p$ and $q$ are true, then $p \implies q$ is correct as well.**

My questions: $(1)$ Is the truth table actually a definition/convention? That is, am I defining the truth values of the symbols there? If so, one could in theory define them arbitrarily right? The problem that would then arise, however, is that our language might/will not be a good model for our reasoning. So the reason why one defines them the way they are is to match what we expect to be the case when reasoning informally, right?

$(2)$ Can I write something like $(p \wedge q) \implies (p \implies q)$ to denote the observation above?

$(3)$ I wondered how one can prove that the method of direct proof actually gives an implication. That is, when assuming $p$ and deducing $q$, why can I deduce $p \implies q$?

$(4)$ Are there deduction rules that use a wrong premise? I know that there is the rule that when $p$ is true and $p \implies q$ is true that one can deduce $q$, which is what one intuitively would think. However, since on defines $p \implies q$ to be true when $p$ is false, are there any deduction rules that are built on this case or are the second and fourth columns just never used? If they are never used, aren't they quite useless and only there to satisfy the claim that they have a truth value?

An attempt to answer $(3)$ might be: If we assume $p$ and can deduce $q$, then we know that whenever $p$ is true, $q$ must also be true. Thus, we can get the cases that both are true, or that $p$ is false. In all of these cases, the implication is true. This appears to be rather informal to me, is there a more formal way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $(1)$ Is the truth table actually a definition/convention? That is, am I defining the truth values of the symbols there? If so, one could in theory define them arbitrarily right? The problem that would then arise, however, is that our language might/will not be a good model for our reasoning. So the reason why one defines them the way they are is to match what we expect to be the case when reasoning informally, right?

Yes! All correct: Yes, it *is* a definition, and yes we can define operators any which way we want. However, in trying to capture the natural 'if ... then ...', the truth-table as defined for the $\to$ seems to be the best candidate.  It's not perfect (see [Paradox of Material Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxes_of_material_implication)) ... but it has some [very good features](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208612/logical-conditional-truth-table-rationale) that do seem to match our conceptual understanding of 'if .. then ..' statements

For example, we have that $P \to P$ is always true. We also have that if we have $P \to Q$, and we have $P$, then we have $Q$. We also have that $P \to Q$ is equivalent to $\neg Q \to \neg P$. We have that if we have $P \to Q$ and $Q \to R$, then we have $P \to R$. So these are all things that totally coincide with our intuitions about the conditional, and there are many more examples like this.

> $(2)$ Can I write something like $(p \wedge q) \implies (p \implies q)$ to denote the observation above?

I think what you really want to write is $P \land Q \Rightarrow P \to Q$. That is: you want to say that the statement $P \to Q$ is true whenever the statement $P \land Q$ is true, i.e. that $P \land Q$ *logically implies* $P \to Q$.  And we typically use $\Rightarrow$ for the *meta-logical* symbol of logical implication, and the $\to$ for the logical symbol of material implication. (indeed, note that I was using $\to$ in the previous point ... I really don't like to see $\Rightarrow$ being used for the material implication, even though several texts and websites.

If you don't like to use meta-logical symbols, then what you can do is to say that the logic statement $(P \land Q) \to (P \to Q)$ is a tautology: a statement that is always true.

By the way, note that $P \to Q$ isn't just True when both $P$ and $Q$ are true ... it is also automatically True just whenever $Q$ is True!  So, we also have $Q \vDash P \to Q$. Or, if you prefer, that $Q \to (P \to Q)$ is a tautology!  And that is actually a pretty good example of where the truth-table for the $\to$ is maybe not such a good match for the English conditional ... we typically don't consider any conditional to be True just because its consequent is True. So this is one of the Paradoxes of Material Implication. These Paradoxes arise because the English conditional isn;t truth-functional .... so *no* truth-table (which inherently assume truth-functionality) is perfect!  But again, the $\to$ is as good as it gets.

> $(3)$ I wondered how one can prove that the method of direct proof actually gives an implication. That is, when assuming $p$ and deducing $q$, why can I deduce $p \implies q$?

Typically, when you assume $P$ and deduce $Q$, you do this within the context of other given statements. So, let's say that $\Gamma$ is the set of statements that you have, that you now assume $P$, and then derive $Q$. What this means is that $P$, together with the given set of statements $\Gamma$, implies $Q$.  This we typically write as $\Gamma, P \vDash Q$.  When you now ask whether this allows us to infer $P \to Q$, you are effectively asking whether $P \to Q$ is a logical consequence of $\Gamma$ alone, i.e. whether $\Gamma \vDash P \to Q$.  And yes, that is indeed the case:  Given that we have that $\Gamma, P \vDash Q$, we know that it is impossible for $Q$ to be False if all statements in $\Gamma$ and statement $P$ are all true.  But that means that it is impossible for $P$ to be True and $Q$ to be False if all statements in $\Gamma$ are True. But that means that $P \to Q$ cannot be False when all statements in $\Gamma$ are True. Hence we have $\Gamma \vDash P \to Q$.  This is the formal semantical justification of a direct (or conditional) proof.

Note that if you don't have any given statements, then $\Gamma$ is the empty set.  But by the above reasoning, that means that if you assume $P$, and derive $Q$, then $P \to Q$ will always be true, i.e. it will be a logical tautology.

> $(4)$ Are there deduction rules that use a wrong premise? I know that there is the rule that when $p$ is true and $p \implies q$ is true that one can deduce $q$, which is what one intuitively would think. However, since on defines $p \implies q$ to be true when $p$ is false, are there any deduction rules that are built on this case or are the second and fourth columns just never used? If they are never used, aren't they quite useless and only there to satisfy the claim that they have a truth value?

I am not so sure I understand the beginning of your question, but I can answer the last part.   No, those values in row 2 and 4 are not useless, and it is easy to come up with deductive rules whose validity relies on those very rows being set to True as they are.

First, consider the following rather trivial inference:

$\therefore P \to P$

That is, from nothing we infer $P \to P$. Is that a valid inference? Sure!  Because $P \to P$ is true no matter whether $P$ is True or False, this should work.  But note: if $P$ is False, then we are dealing with row 4 of the truth-table. So, good thing we defined that as True!  (I told you the truth-table has useful features!)

If you don't like this inference, then how about this one:

$P \to Q$

$\therefore, \neg Q \to \neg P$

This we know as Contraposition (actually, the *equivalence* between these two statements is known as Contraposition, but as an inference from one to the other it should certainly work as well), and again reflects a perfectly intuitively valid inference.  OK, but now consider when we set $P$ and $Q$ both to True. Then, by row 1, $P \to Q$ is True, and hence $\neg Q \to \neg P$ should be True as well.  But both $\neg P$ and $\neg Q$ are False, meaning that we are relying on row 4 to set $\neg Q \to \neg P$ to True. So this inference too relies on row 4 having the truth-value that it does (or at least, that row 1 and row 4 have the same truth-value, but since you are apparently ok with row 1, then yiou should now be ok with row 4 as well)

Next, consider the following pattern, which is known as Weakening the Consequent:

$P \to (Q \land R)$

$\therefore P \to Q$

Again, this *should* be a valid inference pattern, right?  That is, if we know that both $Q$ and $R$ are true when $P$ is True, then *certainly* $Q$ by itself should be true when $P$ is True.

OK, but now consider the following case: Set $P$ and $R$ to False, and $Q$ to True.  This means that $Q \land R$ is False, and hence $P \to (Q \land R)$ is True, because of row 4 of the truth-table.  OK, but then that means that $P \to Q$ should also be true ... and for that we use row 2!

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for taking the time to write this detailed answer. I will probably have to reread it to fully understand everything you wrote, but I have some immediate questions. I thought that formal languages are designed to model/capture our intuitive reasoning. That is, we have some deduction rules that are intuitively true and we then try to formalize them. Additionally we have some "things" that we want to be able to talk about, so we formalize those as well, using predicates, constant symbols, variables etc.

Comment: Then, if we can express something as true in formal language, we can translate it back to natural language to produce true results. So by agreeing on the rules we are certain of in the natural language and translating them to the formal language, we expect the formal language to produce true results when working with it. Couldn't it be problematic then, when our basic rules such as implication are unnatural in the natural language? Couldn't this imply problems such as contradictions?

Comment: Or rather, couldn't it be problematic to encode non-intuitive ideas in our formal language?

Comment: @user103178981 Yes, that is the ideal, and we try to get as close to it as we can.  But no, our truth0functional account of conditionals is not perfect, and it leads to some weird cases.  Think of it as Newtonian mechanics. In most cases Newtonian mechanics matches our observations in the real world. As long as things are not too heavy, or move too fast, it is 'close enough'.  But there are times it fails. When, for example, we want to send a spacecraft close to the sun, we have to start bringing in relativity theory. So, the key is to know when to use the material implication and when not

Comment: In your comment on (3) do you mean "we know that it is impossible for $Q$ to be False if all statements in $Γ$ and statement $P$ are all true"? Or am I missing something there?

Comment: As far as I know, however, FOL is consistent isn't it? Thus defining implication as above, despite having potential inintuitive parts, at least isn't leading to any contradictions. I am not sure if anything "bad" other than contradictions could happen, for example when translating back to natural language.

Comment: Yes, that Q should be a P. Typo, fixed. Thanks for pointing that out .. and good for you for noticing that!

Comment: Hmm, the issue of matching the material implication with the English implication is really a different issue than consistency of FOL.  Consistency of FOL is really about *proof* systems being consistent ... by which we mean that we don;t want our proof systems to be able to derive both a statement $P$ and a statement $\neg P$ starting from nothing. Or more simply: that the proof system isn;t making invalid inferences ... with validity defined relative to whatever semantics we defined. So we could still define $\to$ completely differently.

Comment: Maybe I am talking nonsense. My thought was simply that defining the implication like above could perhaps lead to contradictions, since it doesn't closely match the natural language implication. Thus, when translating back to natural language I feared that it might be possible that one might get contradictions. But I thought that consistency rules that fear out. Again, im not educated at all in this, so I might be saying a lot of nonsense.

Comment: And I can't think of any other "dangers" that could arise from defining it in this or another unintuitive way, other than possible contradictions.

Comment: I have read the wikipedia article that you linked and I thought that it wasn't too bad until I read the example about WW2 in the introduction section of the article. Assigning truth to that statement is really confusing to me. Why do we use this kind of language if it produces results that are this odd? Are there no alternatives or how is this justified? I was just fine with the other examples, but that one is a bit irritating.

Comment: Nice to see almost all forms of “implies”, such as $\to$, $\Rightarrow$, $\vdash$, $\vDash$, $\therefore$, in a single answer to an innocent question about truth tables :)

Comment: @user103178981 Don’ t rely too much on translations from formal to natural language and back. This holds even when “if”/$\Rightarrow$ is not involved. A statement “I was born in Trinidad and Tobago” might be true even though not both of “I was born in Trinidad” an “I was born in Tobago” are true. Or someone might like fish and like chips, but not like fish and chips.

Comment: What real-world problems (e.g. errors or confusion) might arise from considering any conditional to be true "just because its consequent is true?"

Comment: It is widely accepted that natural language is inconsistent. Would the utility of formal logic in science, engineering and commerce not be lost if it was somehow made consistent with a system that is known to be inconsistent? Perhaps we need a "dialect" of natural language that is consistent with classical propositional logic, a dialect in which "X implies Y" is equivalent to "X is false or Y is true."

Comment: I don't consider natural language inconsistent.  Is it widely accepted that it is?  That is news to me. But I do think that natural language is a little different from the languages of logic, mathematics, and science: natural language is often ambiguous, which is the price of it being very efficient.  And to come back to this post: the conditional from natural language just isn't truth-functional. I really don't think we should demand that the English sentence "If grass isn't green, then grass is green" is true just because grass is green.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Right. (2) Right.

(3) An informal way to think about it (similar to what you suggested) is: If you assume $p$ and deduce $q$, then you've shown that we can't have $p$ true and $q$ false together. This rules out the only row of the truth table that makes $(p\implies q)$ false, so you can conclude that $(p\implies q)$ is true. You could formalize this using the axiom $p\lor\lnot p$ and a corresponding proof by cases.

(4) Think about how the explanation above relies on the complete truth table for $(p\implies q)$. If there were a row with $p$ false and $(p\implies q)$ false, then assuming $p$ and deducing $q$ would not be sufficient to conclude that $(p\implies q)$ is true, so $\implies$ would fail to model the intuitive notion of conditional implication.

Here's another argument. We want to be able to compose propositional connectives like $\implies$ with [quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)) like $\forall$. Consider the following true sentence:

> For all real numbers $x$, if $x>10$ then $x>0$.

For the whole $\forall$ sentence to be true, the inner $\implies$ sentence ("if $x>10$ then $x>0$") must be true no matter which number we substitute for $x$. For example, we need "if $3>10$ then $3>0$" to be true. The standard truth table for $\implies$ arises from these considerations.

Answer (score 0):

> (1) Is the truth table actually a definition/convention?

Truth tables are often used to define the standard logical operators, but they can also be formally derived from "first principles", i.e. from basic rules of inference. The truth table for implication, for example, is usually given as:

[image]

This table can be effectively derived by proving the following theorems of propositional logic, each theorem corresponding to a line in the table respectively:

1. $A\land B \to (A\to B)$
2. $A \land \neg B \to \neg(A\to B)$
3. $\neg A \land B \to (A\to B)$
4. $\neg A \land \neg B \to (A\to B)$

Using a form of natural deduction, we can formally derive (1) as follows

[image]

The rule of inference used for each line is given, e.g. line 1 uses the Premise Rule, and line 3 uses the Split Rule applied to line 1.

(That also answers your next question.)

Similarly, (2) can be derived as follows:

[image]

The derivations of (3) and (4) are left as an exercise.