# `if's in formal logic

Tags: first-order-logic

$(\alpha \to \beta) = \neg \alpha \vee \beta $

The truth table is negative when $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = 0$. It is troubling me that $(\alpha \to \beta) \vee (\beta \to \alpha)$ is tautological.

P, Q be $x = 1$, $y = 0$. Then either

1. If $x = 1$ then $y = 0$
2. If $y = 0$ then $x = 1$

Why are they having to end up related? Why is this example wrong? I am studying the book ``Introduction to Formal Logic - Peter Smith" and it says :

``(*if* $= \to$) `$\to$' stands to *some* ‘if’s as $‘\wedge’$ stands to ‘and’ and $‘\vee’$ stands to ‘or’; for the material conditional does at least capture the core logical role
of those ‘if’s which feature in singular indicative conditionals"

What does he mean by *some* `if's?

Comment: Either $x = 1$ or $x \ne 1$; either $y = 0$ or $y \ne 0$. In all four cases, one of 1. and 2. holds.

Comment: See e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208612/how-does-one-obtain-p-implies-q-truth-table) and related ones: the truth-functional def of the [conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) has this "unpleasant feature" that is TRUE when the antecedent is FALSE.

Comment: With "some ‘if’s" the author alludes to the fact that natural language  has several usage of "if"; see [The Logic of Conditionals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-conditionals/) as well as [Indicative Conditionals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/conditionals/) and [Counterfactuals Conditionals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/counterfactuals/).

Comment: The usage of so-called "material conditional" (the formal translation of "if" above) in mathematical logic is due to its link with [Modus Ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) that is the inference rule mostly used in mathematics; see the post regarding [Why do we stick with the material implication?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/69411/why-do-people-use-the-material-implicaton-over-alternatives)